# Java generics challenge

Tags: java, generics

## Description

Firstly, all code to reproduce is shown below as well as with a UML diagram of the implementation. I understand that the naming I have gone for can be confusing, but I'm not able to come up with anything better for this minimal working example of my issue at hand.

The essence of the problem is in class `AChildOne` and is related to these three lines of code:

```
List<C<B>> cBList = new ArrayList<>();
List<C<BChild>> cBChildList = aChildTwo.get();
cBList.addAll(cBChildList);  // <-- COMPILATION ERROR
```

If I change the first line in the above code snippet to:

```
List<C<? extends B>> cBList = new ArrayList<>();
```

the specific compilation error goes away, but it breaks other parts of the class.

If I remove the container class `C` from this implementation, things seem to work. However, in the actual implementation it does a bit more than what is shown in this minimal example so it is not so easy to remove it.

I was thinking that I would like to do something like this:

```
public class AChildOne implements A<? extends B>
```

but this is not allowed.

**I suppose the problem is that I'm not able to successfully combine the generics for the return value of `AChildOne::get()` with the return value of `AChildTwo::get()`.**

I suspect that what I'm trying to do here is one of those 'gotchas' with generics, that you are not allowed to do.

### Side note

Using `Number`, `Integer` and `Double` instead of my own classes, I'm essentially trying to do something like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<C<Integer>> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
    integerList.add(new C<>(1));

    List<C<Double>> doubleList = new ArrayList<>();
    doubleList.add(new C<>(3.14));

    List<C<? extends Number>> numberList = new ArrayList<>();

    numberList.addAll(integerList);
    numberList.addAll(doubleList);

    numberList.forEach(n -> System.out.println(n.value));
  }
```

which does indeed work (`C` here is the same `C` as implemented below). However, when wrapping these things in separate classes, and using inheritance, it does not seem like I'm able to propagate the generics properly. If ONLY I could do this:

```
public class AChildOne implements A<? extends B>
```

I think it would work.

## UML diagram

[image: uml diagram]

## Code

```
import java.util.List;

public interface A<T> {
  List<C<T>> get();
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AChildOne implements A<B> {

  private final AChildTwo aChildTwo = new AChildTwo();

  public List<C<B>> get() {
    List<C<B>> cBList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<C<BChild>> cBChildList = aChildTwo.get();

    cBList.addAll(cBChildList);  // <-- COMPILATION ERROR

    return cBList;
  }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AChildTwo implements A<BChild> {
  List<C<BChild>> list = new ArrayList<>();

  public List<C<BChild>> get() {
    return list;
  }
}
```

```
public class B {
}
```

```
public class BChild extends B {
}
```

```
public class C<T> {
  T value;

  public C(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  T get() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that answers this question, because the class inheritance part seems crucial here. I added a 'side note' section where I use `Number`, `Integer` and `Double` to demonstrate the list constructs that I'm after. These list constructs work, but the problem is related to the fact that I'm not able to propagate generics through inheritance in the right manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AChildOne` cannot implement `A<B>`, because it cannot supply a `List<C<B>>`. It supplies a `List<C<BChild>>` (the return type of `aChildTwo.get()`). A `List<C<BChild>>` *is not a subtype of* `List<C<B>>`. If it were, it would break type safety:

```
List<C<BChild>> a = ...;
List<C<B>> b = a; // suppose you could do this
C<B> c = b.get(0);
c.value = new AnotherChildOfB();
BChild bchild = a.get(0).get(); // this would get an AnotherChildOfB instance, but is declared to return a BChild.
```

As you have correctly identified, `AChildOne.get` could return a `List<C<? extends B>>`. **You would need to change the interface method's signature** to make this work, rather than changing the inheritance clause.

Alternatively, `AChildOne` could implement `A<BChild>`. I actually recommend you choose this solution, because [returning a wildcard is likely a code smell](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1452).

Comment: It’s perhaps worth noting that there’s also no subtype relationship between `C<B>` and `C<BChild>`. The OP seems to have covariance in mind, as `C` only has a `get()` method, but that’s not how Java’s generics work. Someone could create a subclass of `C` which has a `set` method, so there’s no covariance for classes but only for use sites, which we would declare via `C<? extends B>`. But even then, as correctly explained in the answer, a `List<C<BChild>>` could not get assigned to a variable of type `List<C<? extends B>>`.